# What does "combining the solutions in O(n) time" mean?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

> Algorithm $X$ proceeds by recursively solving $5$ subproblems of
>   one-half the size, then combining the solutions in $O(n\log n)$ time.
>
> Algorithm $Y$ makes $9$ recursively calls on subproblems with
>   one-third the size, then combining the solutions in $O(n^2)$ time.

What do the last parts of these sentences mean? "Combining the solutions in $O(...)$ time? Can we represent $X$ and $Y$ by:

$$X(n) = 5X(n/2)+n\log n$$

$$Y(n)=9Y(n/3)+n^2$$

Or does it mean something different?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: I think you may need to to put $O(\cdots )$ on the right hand side, or at least multiply $n \log n$ and $n^2$ by unknown constants